# Ionic 3 add class dynamically if the input is not valid

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework, ionic3, formbuilder

Hi I am using Ionic 3 and I am using [formBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) of **Angular** to validate my **form inputs** and display some **validation messages** to the UI of the component when something goes wrong with the **input**.

Now everything works fine except for one. I want to add **class dynamically** to my input when the `input field` is not **valid**.

Picture below.

[image]

Here is what it looks like in my **html**

```
 <ion-input class="input-cover" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name *"
            [class.invalid]="form.controls['firstName'].errors && (form.controls['firstName'].dirty || form.controls['firstName'].touched)"></ion-input>
```

and in my **scss** I have this below

```
.invalid {
        border: 1px solid #ea6153;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

.text-input-ios, .text-input-md {
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #efefef;
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my **dynamic class**?

I assume that the `dynamic class` is wrong and my form builder is working fine because the **validation messages** is popping up.

Here is all of my **scss code**

```
page-register {
// ion-input {
//     border: 5px !important;
// }

.upload-cover-button{
    position: relative;
    button{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
}

button{
    border-radius: 4px !important;
}

.text-input-ios, .text-input-md {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.text-input {
    margin: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    padding: 13px 8px;
}

hr {
     height: 1px !important;
}

.input-cover {
    position: static;
}

.col-static {
    position : initial !important;
}

ion-select {
    padding: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    max-width: 100%;
}

img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 80px;
}

.center-vertical-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button-spinner {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.register-spinner {
    * {
        stroke: white !important;
    }
}

.error-message {
    color: #ea6153;
}

.invalid {
    border: 1px solid #ea6153;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

}

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take a look at [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: I tried this but still won't work `[ngClass]="form.controls['firstName'].errors && (form.controls['firstName'].dirty || form.controls['firstName'].touched) ? 'invalid' : ''"`

Comment: Try like this `[ngClass]="{
  invalid: condition
}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
<ion-input class="input-cover" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name *"
            [ngClass]="{'invalid' : form.controls['firstName'].errors && (form.controls['firstName'].dirty || form.controls['firstName'].touched)}"></ion-input>
```

Add this to your scss

```
 .invalid input {
    border: 1px solid #ea6153;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

Comment: didn't workout this is the **style** when I try to `console.log()` the input and view its source.

`page-register .text-input {
    margin: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    padding: 13px 8px;
}

page-register .text-input-ios, page-register .text-input-md {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ea6153;
}
.text-input-ios {
    margin: 11px 8px 11px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
}`

Comment: I also tried to put the **style** manually without the conditions but didn't worked maybe because of this **scss line** below

`.text-input-ios, .text-input-md {
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #efefef;
    }`

or this

`ion-input {
        border: 5px !important;
    }`

Comment: do you see the class added?

Comment: Nope. I tried it manually even without the conditions. I tried to even use **inline-style** but didn't workout

Comment: you don't see the class added to the ion-input like [this](https://imgur.com/a/WyKQ3QM) ?

Comment: Sorry when I removed this `ion-input {
        border: 5px !important;
    }` from my **scss** it worked but the border is too large.

Comment: Edited it. @Sabyasachi Patra

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177460/discussion-between-sabyasachi-patra-and-knowledgeseeker).

Comment: Personally I'd use `[class.invalid]="form.get('firstName').invalid && (form.get('firstName').dirty || form.get('firstName').touched)"`.